# History about complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, book-recommendation, math-history

I would like to find a book that introduces the history of theorems in complex analysis, or one that covers similar topics in complex analysis. For example, I want to know who came up with the maximum modulus principle in the first place, and under what circumstances.

Comment: Perhaps better suited to http://hsm.stackexchange.com

Comment: Have you Googled "history of complex analysis"?

Comment: See https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-23715-2 and https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1987-17-01/S0273-0979-1987-15559-5/S0273-0979-1987-15559-5.pdf and http://www.math.snu.ac.kr/~ckhan/mathhistory/complexhistory/complexhistory091008.pdf for instance

Comment: Look directly at the publications from the famous (German and French) names of 1820-60, in 59 Riemann knew most of what we know.